# Pick a color according to current colormap

Tags: matlab, colors, surface

My graph contains a number of semi-transparent isosurfaces to visualize density. I choose the color for a range 70:140:

```
vs=griddata(x,y,z,v,xs,ys,zs,'linear');
for i=70:5:140
  p(i)=patch(isosurface(xs,ys,zs,vs,i));
  isonormals(xs,ys,zs,vs,p(i));
  rd=(i-70)/70;
  set(p(i),'facealpha',0.5);
  set(p(i),'FaceColor',[rd 0 1-rd],'EdgeColor','none'); % set colors
end;
alpha(0.3);
```

So, here the colors vary from blue (density=70) to red (density=140).
How to get a color for a given range from the current colormap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation explains [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html) how the values are mapped to the colormap using the `fix` function.

Here is an example for the range you gave, where the color can be accessed using `cmap(index(i),:)` for an `i` in the range `rng`:

```
rng=70:5:140;
cmap = colormap;
m = size(cmap,1);
index = fix((rng-min(rng))/range(rng)*m)+1;
index(index<1) = 1;
index(index>m) = m;

% Plot example
hold on;
arrayfun(@(i) plot(rng(i),rng(i),'.', ...
    'markersize',30,'color',cmap(index(i),:)),1:length(rng));
colorbar; hold off;
```

This example outputs the following plot:
[image: image of matlab plot]

Comment: Thanks, a simple and useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are asking but you could also check out the command `caxis` which will set the scaling of colors based on a range given to the current `colormap`. Can be used along with a function like `hsv` to set a colormap to the requested length and scale the values into that range.

As in,

```
     colormap(hsv(71));
     caxis([70 140]);
     patch(isosurface(x,y,z,v,c))
     ...
```